# SQL: Consolidating category items

Tags: sql, database, sas

Can you please advise how to consolidate non-numerical values using SQL?
I have the following data table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14spT.png)
I want to make it look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGrGP.png)

Creating select distinct will not solve things...

Just to add, in fields marked '.' there is precisely a dot symbol.
Can you please advise how to create target dataset?

Thank you very much for your help and advise!

I expect the outcome defined above.
I am using SAS, but work in Proc SQL mode.

Comment: Please don't link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Why do you have character variables with strings consisting of a single period?  Are you sure those are not numeric variables with a format attached?  What was the source of the data? Did you create the variables using the $CHAR informat instead of the normal $ informat?

Comment: Is there some reason why you would need to use PROC SQL code instead of some other PROC or a DATA step?

Answer (score 1):

Can use Aggregate functions:

```
select ID, RA1, max(RA2)RA2, max(RA3)RA3 from TableA
group by ID,RA1
```

or for removing '.':

```
select * from (
select ID, RA1, max(RA2)RA2, max(RA3)RA3 from TableA
group by ID,RA1
)as B
where RA1!='.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use SAS and don't know what "Proc SQL mode" is, but - see if aggregation helps (it does in pure SQL):

```
select id,
  max(rating_agency_1) ra1,
  max(rating_agency_2) ra2,
  max(rating_agency_3) ra3
from your_table
group by id
```